# Eigen library: pass array of Vector4f to OpenCL kernel as floats

Tags: opencl, eigen

I have a list of vectors that I need to transform by matrices on the CPU. I am storing these as a dynamically allocated array (Eigen::Vector4f*). Once they have been transformed I need to run an OpenCL kernel on the vectors. I'm wondering what the best way is to pass this data into OpenCL without having to copy the data from Eigen::Vector --> float array as this will be fairly costly.  My understanding is that Eigen internally stores the vectors values in some sort of buffer I can access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways,

1 - The best is probably to use a `Matrix4Xf` because it allows to work on the whole set of vectors at once:

```
Matrix4Xf vecs(4,n);
Matrix4f transform;
vecs = transform * vecs;
vecs.row(1)     // read-write access to all y components
vecs.col(i)     // read-write access to i-th vector
float* raw_ptr = vecs.data();
```

2 - use a `std::vector<Vector4f>` (same as Vector4f* but no memory management issues):

```
std::vector<Vector4f> vecs(n);
for(auto& v:vecs) v = transform * v;
float* raw_ptr = vecs[0].data(); // assuming vecs is not empty
// you can still see it as Matrix4Xf:
Map<Matrix4Xf> vecs_as_mat(raw_ptr,4,n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay -- did a bit more research. The solution is to use the raw buffers exposed by the Eigen::Map class:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMapClass.html

I can create a raw buffer of floats then create Eigen::Map objects that wrap the float buffers into vectors.